# Power BI Dax measure not summing correctly for conditional formatting

Tags: powerbi, switch-statement, dax, conditional-formatting, measure

**EDIT** I have tried the ALL() for both locations and Part Code and it is still not applying the conditional formatting correctly.

I am attempting to add conditional formatting to a column in a table in a Power Bi report - this is values based to alert the team with a quick glance if something is low or close to being out of stock so they can reorder before that happens.

First, I have a measure to sum my quantities.

```
`Quantity Sum = 
     CALCULATE(
          SUM('FIN IC_BIN_DETAIL_STATUS'[Quantity])
          ,'FIN IC_BIN_DETAIL_STATUS'[Part Code]
     )`
```

Second, I have a column created using a switch formula:

```
`OOS Column = 
SWITCH(
    TRUE(),
    'FIN IC_BIN_DETAIL_STATUS'[Part Code] ="500107" && [Quantity Sum] >= 401, "Green",
    'FIN IC_BIN_DETAIL_STATUS'[Part Code] ="500107" && [Quantity Sum] >= 201, "Yellow",
    'FIN IC_BIN_DETAIL_STATUS'[Part Code] ="500107" && [Quantity Sum] <= 200, "Red",
    'FIN IC_BIN_DETAIL_STATUS'[Part Code] ="500108" && [Quantity Sum] >= 151, "Green",
    'FIN IC_BIN_DETAIL_STATUS'[Part Code] ="500108" && [Quantity Sum] >= 51, "Yellow",
    'FIN IC_BIN_DETAIL_STATUS'[Part Code] ="500108" && [Quantity Sum] <= 50, "Red",
    'FIN IC_BIN_DETAIL_STATUS'[Part Code] ="500233" && [Quantity Sum] >= 151, "Green",
    'FIN IC_BIN_DETAIL_STATUS'[Part Code] ="500233" && [Quantity Sum] >= 51, "Yellow",
    'FIN IC_BIN_DETAIL_STATUS'[Part Code] ="500233" && [Quantity Sum] <= 50, "Red", "Blue"
)`
```

And third I have another measure to assign a value to the color codes to allow for conditional formatting.

```
`OOS Measure = 
      SWITCH(
          MAX('FIN IC_BIN_DETAIL_STATUS'[OOS Column])
         ,"Red",1
         ,"Yellow",2
         ,"Green",3
         ,"Blue",4
         ,5
      )`
```

My problem is the 'FIN IC_BIN_DETAIL_STATUS' table has locations and when I apply the conditional formatting, the colors are wrong. The measure seems to be summing each location individually instead of the part code in whole, so the colors are incorrect unless the values I am looking for are correct in the individual locations. Is there a way to get the sum to look at everything and ignore the locations? Every table I can look at for this information *theoretically* will have the same issue because they are all location based.

Comment: Have you tried using ALL()?

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
Quantity Sum = CALCULATE(SUM('FIN IC_BIN_DETAIL_STATUS'[Quantity]),ALL('FIN IC_BIN_DETAIL_STATUS'[Part Code]))
```

for your measure.

This should ignore the location filtering on the Part Code in your table visuals.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and unfortunately it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:(Ignore the filter on location column)

```
Your_Measure =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'FIN IC_BIN_DETAIL_STATUS'[Quantity] ),
    ALL('FIN IC_BIN_DETAIL_STATUS'[location] )
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately it still did not resolve the issue.

Comment: Hi Briana! Please share your datasets and data model! It is hard to help , considering limited information! Btw, The second argument of Your measure 'Quantity Sum' is incorrect! It must specify a filter condition! Like this: 'FIN IC_BIN_DETAIL_STATUS'[Part Code] = 500233 or remove it altogether!

Comment: I actually tackled this from a slightly different angle, by creating a new table using dax and then adding my formulas with some minor modifications like using FILTER and IN VALUES. Thanks though!